# Pop-up o mensaje cuando se haga clic en un div

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo contenido dentro de un div, y quiero que cuando alguien haga clic le salte un mensaje, como pop-up o como mensaje del navegador con javascript algo asi, cuando hagan click en cualquier lado del contenedor div.
No tengo idea si esto se puede hacer.

Gracias.

Comment: Postea tu código para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un código sencillo que te permite mostrar un pop-up al dar clic en un `<div>`, para esto se utiliza código **HTML** para definir el `<div>`, **CSS** para la creación del pop-up y su contenedor, y **JavaScript** para definir la función.

```js
// Cuando el usuario cliclea el <div>, el popup se abre
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Contenedor del popup */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* pop-up actual */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Muestra del Pop-up*/
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Cambio para mostrar/ocultar el contenedor del pop-up */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Animación del pop-up */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<center>
<br><br><br>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">¡Dame clic!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Texto del contenedor</span>
</div>
</center>
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: Si algo si queria, gracias.

Comment: No sabes si se puede agregar css a los alerts?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cambiar el color al mensaje del pop-up?

Comment: Si, pero no de ese, osea de un alert, con java

Comment: Un alert de los que te muestra el navegador por defecto (utilizando alert() ), no se puede modificar, sin embargo puedes agregar un alert utilizando HTML, CSS y JavaScript, aqui te dejo un ejemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_alert

Comment: creo que él se refiere a una ventana modal completa, similar al alert. para eso debe usar html y css o usar una api que haga [ventanas modales](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: Gracias @CristianAgudelo Si se refiere a algún modal, puede utilizar Bootstrap, ya que es fácil de implementar y contiene animación, este lo puede probar aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h